# Provision Azure AD from GSuite Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, google-workspace, provisioning

I'm trying to setup SSO and provisioning from my directory on GSuite to an Azure AD.
There's no problem with SSO, besides the fact that you need to first create the guest accounts on the AAD side.

I've searched around on how to provision AAD from GSuite, but the few documentations/forum posts I found all point to it being impossible in this direction without making some custom scripting.

Is there a hidden way I haven't found? If not, where can I find information on how to set up this custom implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/g-suite-provisioning-tutorial#step-3-add-g-suite-from-the-azure-ad-application-gallery? What do you mean by "custom scripting" here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that the document is in the wrong direction: "provisioning to G Suite", whereas I want to provision my AAD from GSuite. :)

Comment: I think Microsoft doesn't provide such tool or feature currently. You should look into Google Cloud Directory Sync: https://support.google.com/a/answer/106368?hl=en

Comment: Yup that's why I came to the idea of a custom script of whatever, to fetch from GSuite and provision programmatically the AAD. I've looked into GCDS, but it only does LDAP -> GSuite :(